# How to design elasticsearch index for my data?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are currently building some search engine for our internal data and we are using ElasticSearch for that. **Our data looks like this:**

- Object A: {attribute_a_1, attribute_a_2} - 100M of object A;
- Object B: {attribute_b_1, attribute_b_2} - 200M of object B;
- Object C: {attribute_c_1, attribute_c_2} - 50M of object C.

**Now the relationships are:**

- Each of object A can have none or one or many objects B;
- Each of object A can have none or one or many objects C.

**My goal is to have index which can be really fast searched for:**

- Objects A - by using its own and other objects attributes;
- Objects B - by using its own and other objects attributes.

**Example:**

Find all objects B where attribute_a_1="something", attribute_b_2="something", attribute_c_1="something".

**Currently we are using nested structures:**

```
PUT object_a
{
    "mapping": {
        "properties": {
            "attribute_a_1": {...},
            "attribute_a_2": {...},
            "object_b": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "attribute_b_1": {...},
                    "attribute_b_2": {...}
                }
            },
            "object_c": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "attribute_c_1": {...},
                    "attribute_c_2": {...}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Performance isn't bad, but having some objects A, which contains hundreds of thousands of objects B and object C, really slow down the querying. We know that this design costs a lot of resources to update data, but we don't do often updates, so this is not a problem. Any suggestions how can we improve our index design? Maybe we are thinking all wrong. I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: denormalize, denormalize , denormalize  :)

Comment: But since objects B and objects C both have relationships with Object A, this would create at least 200M(objects B) * 50M (objects C) documents. Which is 1*10^16 documents.

Comment: nested documents also create addition documents, you can index a sample document and check the _count api in your index